# PHP+MYSQL: error move_uploaded_file() unable to move

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, image-upload

I'm stucked in one place, I have a file upload php file but when I want to upload the image I have errors called:
"Warning: move_uploaded_file(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.." and
"Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php7E6D.tmp' to 'site/images/UBI30_Giveaway_box_CARDS_1.jpg'.. "
My Upload php looks like this:

```
//Image datas
$target_dir = "site/images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Submint button pressed?
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $nev=$_POST['nev'];
  $about=$_POST['about'];
  $image=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

// Does it image?
      if($check !== false) {
          echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
          $uploadOk = 1;
      } else {
          echo "File is not an image.";
          $uploadOk = 0;
      }

//Recently the image is uploaded?
      if (file_exists($target_file)) {
      echo "Sajnáljuk, ez már egy feltöltött fájl..";
      $uploadOk = 0;
      }

//If everything okay, upload.
      if ($uploadOk == 0) {
      echo "Sajnáljuk a kép nem került feltöltésre..";
      } else {
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
              echo "A ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " feltöltve.";
          } else {
              echo "Sajnáljuk, hiba történt a kép feltöltése közben.";
          }
      }
  }
// Upload datas to db.
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `jelolt`(`name`, `about`, `image`) VALUES ('$nev','$about','$image')");
    $stmt->execute();
// A lekérdezés helyes futásának ellenörzése.
      if (!$stmt) {
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
      }
```

I hope you guys can be clever than  me, I'm just don't find my bug around 3 hours ago.

**UPDATE** with `$target_dir = getcwd();` modify this start work but not put the correct folder, and if I change the url I got the same problem . I need to attach /views/site/image url after getcwd() but of corse it's doesn't work for me: `$target_dir = getcwd()."views/site/image";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getcwd()` returns your current working directory. If you add v`iews/site/image` to it, you will get the folder where your page is in + the path you expect. You need a slash at the end as well, like `views/site/image`. If your page is not inside the root folder and it is fairly safe to assume this as your current case, for instance, this is a page called `foo/bar`, then your file will be tried to be uploaded into the `foo` folder, however, your `views` folder is probably in your web root. So you need to define the position compared to root, like this:  `dirname(__FILE__)."views/site/image/".$yourfilename`. Make sure you have the necessary privileges for all the folders in the path.

Comment: I have all the permission for all folder so it is should be code problem, I used your recommendation but I still have an error, can we make private conversation? I'm hungarian as well.

Comment: @BenceKurucz I know you are, however, I am speaking in English here to make sure others understand us as well. I wonder what your error is in the most recent version and I wonder how this version looks alike.

Comment: @BenceKurucz in an eventual conversation between the two of us we can use our language of course, but we need to use English here in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

I am not near my tools to test this, but from eyelevel view, it seems that you moving the imagesize response and not the file.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
```

should probably be:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], $target_file)) {
```

I can't see anything else at the moment, other than the variables being mixed up there. It seems your uploaded file will be in "name" not "tmp_name". If no one comes up with an answer by the time I am at my workstation, i will run this through a test.

Comment: I'm testing with `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], $target_file)) {` but doesn't work for me. I don't have the error but the image is not inserted anywhere, but thanks the help.